# Linux driver for Bigfoot Killer E2100...?

Tags: linux, networking, drivers

I have looked around online a bit, but have not been able to find any drivers to make a Bigfoot Killer E2100 work under Linux (CentOS 6, for what it's worth). The one candidate I found required a few tweaks to get to compile, but after compiling, it doesn't seem to work... I suspect that it might require recompiling the kernel, which if it doesn't do this automatically, I seem incapable of doing manually. More on this patch is given later...

We really, really don't care whether we get the full benefit of this device... it seems like it's a device unto itself, as it shows up as a Power PC upon lspci. If we can just get basic - even slow, if that's what it comes down to - functionality out of this thing - the bare minimum of compatibility mode - that is all we need, at least until somebody comes out with a better driver, or we invest some cheap cash into a couple of extra NICs.

So, about the patch... it's a few .C and .H files and an executable (looks like a module or something) which, when run, gives an error of "cannot find module chipreg". Maybe I shouldn't be trying to run this thing at all. Anyway, after following the advice on a few websites to get the code to compile (looks like it's compiling locally to /usr/src/kernels/*/), upon reboot nothing seems to have changed. Do I need to select a different kernel at startup, or specifically trigger a complete recompilation of the kernel first? The driver is sort of old, and I'm thinking it might be a compatibility-mode thing for all Killer cards, but maybe it's just not the right driver at all. For what it's worth, the E2100 is integrated on the Gigabyte MBs we bought, and we're running CentOS 6.0 (based on RHEL).

I really feel like I'm over my head here... any help is appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, I've found a couple Google results mentioning that the manufacturer is "Cabletron". Is this the case, or am I seeing results from some other E2100? (There also seems to be a module for this in the kernel, so you may not have to patch it, if this is the E2100 you are talking about).

Comment: I haven't seen this association yet, but I will follow up on it and see where it takes me. If it's the 2100 that comes integrated on Sniper MBs by Gigabyte and it's also related to Bigfoot Networks, then we might be in a great success situation. Thanks!